# Symfony2 can check if a route is valid for the user who is currently logged in

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony2 can check if a route is valid for the user who is currently logged in, I need to build a dynamic menu.
For example I would like to check if the user (role) can access those routes, just to show that you can access routes.

```
$menu->addChild('Home', array ('route' => 'homepage'));
$menu->addChild('About Me', array (
    'route' => 'page_show'
    'routeParameters' => array ('id' => 42)
));
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You don't explain what is the context, you are in a controller ?

Comment: I bet he's using KnpMenuBundle. So I guess he's in a service.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like (from the code) that you are using KnpMenuBundle.

Which means, if it's the case, that you are in a service.

Simply inject in your MenuBuilder service the `security_context` service, so you can check if your user can access to a link.

```
#MenuBuilder.php

if $securityContext->getToken()->getUser() && $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') {
    $menu->addChild('Administration', array("route" => ......);
}
```

Yet, you need to secure the route in the controller using annotation :

```
    /**
     * Administration index page
     *
     * @Route("/administration/index", name="administration_index")
     * @Template
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
     *
     * @return array|Response
     */
```